# How can I print a quoted string and a variable in Python?

Tags: python, string, apostrophe

I need to do it in a single line. With 2 tabs:

```
      Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
```

The code

```
famous_person = "Albert Einstein"
message ='\t\tf{famous_person} once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
print(message)
```

But `f{}` is not working I guess :(

Comment: the `f` for an f-string needs to be outside of the string before the opening quote: `f'{famous_person}'`, not `'f{famous_person}'`

Comment: The title of this question asks a different question to the question asked in the body

Answer (score 1):

You can. Put `f` character just before a string like `f'...{...}...'`, not `'f{...}'`.

```py
famous_person = "Albert Einstein"
message =f'\t\t{famous_person} once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
print(message)
```

`'\t\tAlbert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'`

Reference
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

Move `f` into the first of the line, I mean instead of `'...f{...}..,'` do `f'...{...}...'`

```
famous_person = "Albert Einstein"
message =f'\t\t{famous_person} once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just started out in python use a simple `+` to **concantenate** strings.
In:

```
famous_person = "Albert Einstein"
message = famous_person+"\tonce said, 'A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.'"
print(message)
```

Out:
`Albert Einstein    once said, 'A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.'`